# Trouble using If Then function

Tags: excel-formula

I am trying to create an Excel document where I say if one cell says dismissed then the other cell should say No Intake Completed, if it says pending then the second cell would say awaiting intake.  If it says neither I would like the next cell to remain blank.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), look around, and read through the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)? If you run into a specific problem, research it thoroughly, search thoroughly here, and if you're still stuck post your code and a description of the problem. Also, remember to include [Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). People will be glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple if statement

```
=IF(A1="dismissed","No Intake Completed", IF(A1="pending","awaiting intake", IF(A1="neither","", "It is something else")))
```

It is checking value in A1 according to the logic you have written in your question.